# tuples with unicode fix

Tags: python, sql, unicode, tuples, ascii

I have some tuples from an sql query that are a list of album names. However, they output in unicode giving it u' before each name, which I would like to remove. It prints out like this:

```
((u'test',), (u'album test',), (u'test!',), (u'',), (u'album1',), (u'album2',), (u'album3',), (u'testalbum',))
```

but i'm looking for just the names such as: test, test, album1, album2 etc.

I've tried using a for loop to encode each album name indivudally, but then i get:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any suggestions? 
thank you for your feedback!

Comment: The tuples look weird. Why are their second elements missing? A string like `u'something'` is known as a unicode string. The rules for converting a Unicode string into the ASCII encoding, for example, are simple; for each code point: If the code point is < 128, each byte is the same as the value of the code point. If the code point is 128 or greater, the Unicode string can't be represented in this encoding. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Also, please provide your code.

Comment: Also don't post images.  Hard to cut-n-paste to formulate an answer.

Comment: @sam `(u'test')` isn't a tuple; it is a string with parentheses around it.  `(u'test',)` is a one-element tuple.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oh thank you so much for pointing that out. Didn't know that!

Comment: @sam Also FYI, parentheses for the tuple aren't required either, but they are shown for display.  `t = u'test',` is also a one-element tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are calling `encode()` on the tuple. You really should be calling `encode()` on the (Unicode) string, which is the first element of the tuple.

---

For example,

```
>>> t = (u'hello', u'world')
>>> t.encode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
>>> t[0].encode()
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the default output of tuples and Unicode strings, print the strings:

```
>>> t=(u'test',),(u'album test',),(u'test!',),(u'',),(u'album1',),(u'album2',),(u'album3',),(u'testalbum',)
>>> for item in t:
...   print item[0]
...
test
album test
test!

album1
album2
album3
testalbum
```